# Why can't I modify superclass attribute's value with ctypes Structure?

Tags: python, ctypes

I have two classes Foo and Foo2. Foo shall have a generic attribute that shall be modified later with a Foo2 instance.
Here's the code:

```
from ctypes import *

class Foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('address', c_uint32)]
    _var = None

    @property
    def var(self):
        return self._var

    def __init__(self, var=0):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        self.var = var

    @var.setter
    def var(self, value):
        self._var = value


class Foo2(Foo):
    _fields_ = [('First', Foo),
            ('Second', Foo)]

    def __init__(self):
        super(Foo2, self).__init__(var=0)
```

When I try to do the following:

```
b = Foo2()
b.var = 0xff
print(hex(b.var))
b.First.var = 0
b.Second.var = 1
print(b.First.var)
print(b.Second.var)
```

I can only access and modify the inherited var, but not the var of the Foo objects First and Second as the result is always None. What am I missing?

Any help is really appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: What's the end goal of this question?

Comment: I am communicating with a micro through a rs232 with which I read/write on 32bit registers with common structures but different addresses. The idea was creating a common structure and programmatically change the address value according to the register I need to access. This structure resides in a generic "RegisterClass" that is istantiated when I start my interface. In this case, 'First' and 'Second' represents the first two register on which I'd like to change the var attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too had this problem.  It's very strange, and I presume that ctypes is doing something "non-standard" with the Structure class.  I was able to work around the problem put using something like this:

```
@property
def var(self):
    return (self.address * 2)
```

in cases where I could compute my var from the *fields* of self.  Perhaps *fields* is like *slots*, and supposedly is limiting the creation of new attributes.